# How do I make my system detect ubuntu?

Tags: boot, windows-7

I have two partitions one is ext4 for ubuntu 500 gb and other is ntfs for windows 500 gb again.
But the syetem automatically boots to windows without detecting ubuntu and also does not detect the 500 gb media drive but the live cd does.
I tried searching everywhere but cannot find the solution.

Comment: Is that windows 8.1 by any chance?

Comment: No, I am using windows 7 ultimate 64-bit. and also am not being able to connect to the internet because I dont' have the drivers